# Python subprocess reading

Tags: python, subprocess

Having this code

> ```
> p = subprocess.Popen('tail -f /var/log/syslog', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
>
> for line in p.stdout.readlines():
>     print line,
>     time.sleep(1)
> ```

The script hangs and does not write any lines even if I add something to syslog.

Why?

Comment: Do I have to run the Popen in another thread?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

readlines() will not return until there is an eof on the process, which there won't be as tail never finishes without an interrupt.

You could change your loop to:

```
while True:
    print(p.stdout.readline())
```

Unless you want an additional 1s gap between each line., there is no need for a sleep as readline will block, using minimal resources, until there is a full line available.

Comment: hey @linuts, I am doing something similar but after sometime, I dont get anything in 'p.stdout.readline()' and it keeps waiting while if I manually tail the file from commandline, logs are still coming.



inline `haproxy_log_file = '/tmp/filebeat/filebeat'
f = subprocess.Popen(['sudo','tail','-F',haproxy_log_file],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
while True:
    line = f.stdout.readline()`

Answer (score 2):

You could also emulate `tail -f` directly in python.

Check this: [tail -f in Python (Python recipe)](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/157035-tail-f-in-python/)

Or this: [Emulate the "tail -f" command](http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet2145.htm) or Google for more examples.